# user32 and kernel method list for C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there a good list of what we can import from `user32.dll` and `kernel.dll` and use in C#?
I am new to Windows API and I want to know more about those two libraries.

Comment: Reading MSDN on functions you are interested in may be better way of learning... I.e. some lightweight reading about files can be found in [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) function. In general looking at function signatures not going to give you much - picking up "Windows Internals" maybe another approach to learn about these...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://www.pinvoke.net/ is the best place to look up examples of API's.

Also the Help Manual with Visual Studio 6 has a Win32.chm.

Here is a link to the VS2008 documentation (2.2GB) and it has 99% of the win32 API info:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20955&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True