# C# - mshtml and SHDocVw Complete Documentation

Tags: c#, mshtml, shdocvw, microsoft.mshtml, shdocvw.internetexplorer

I'm not sure if this is a valid question here but I am having a hard time finding proper documentation for these 2 DLLs, **mshtml** and **SHDocVw**.

I'm trying to do some automation using these 2 DLLs. To do that, I must read and understand first what these 2 libraries contain, all its methods, functions, etc.

But I can't seem to find any complete documentation online. I tried checking in MSDN and even in Microsoft but it is somewhat lacking in information. For example, I can't find any information regarding HTMLInputTextElement and IHTMLSelectElement.

I'd like to ask for your help on websites/books that contain adequate/complete information on these 2 libraries. I hope you guys can point me to them.

Comment: Those DLLs are as old as IE6. Back then they were documented in the Help guide. I was looking for it ages ago as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667551/user32-and-kernel-method-list-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found documentation for MSHTML:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741317(v=vs.85)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741322(VS.85).aspx

SHDocVW is basically IE, I dug around and found this: https://web.archive.org/web/20070416164409/http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/browser/webbrowser/WebBrowser.asp

Comment: thank you Jeremy. are these DLLs stable to use? I'm a bit concerned on its stability since it doesn't seem to be updated and supported. And there doesn't seem to be a lot of people who use it.

Comment: I'd use Chromium if you can, it's for Chrome browser. Those 2 DLLs are so old <insert your Momma joke>. Why do you want to use them, screen scraping? Just use HttpClient .Net class or the tool WGET.

Comment: unfortunately, we have to. I personally would rather use Selenium or other DLLs that are updated and heavily supported by the community but since we work with IE, we were told to 'maximize' the potential of the libraries provided by Microsoft. I already foresee a great challenge just troubleshooting errors due to the fact that I can't find help online because these libraries are rarely used I guess.

Comment: So some *person* reckons 'maximize' the potential of the **22 year old** binaries? hahaha!!! Tell whoever told you that - that "competitive advantage flows not from the technology itself, but rather from the ability to understand and deploy it to meet customer needs" - Martin Fowler. Unless your customer is Chinese and using Tomato Garden version of WindowsXP with IE6 then you're not going to meet the clients needs.